# Retrieving value from database in CodeIgniter is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my Codeigniter project ,table value is not retrieving from database.Am using MySQL (WAMP) as database.Using  Select Query i have checked the data in database and its fine there.When updating the same also its retrieving the old value in db.But when retrieving the value in later stage (ie,taking old bill) its not retrieving the value.The problem is happening only on the single field(ie,actual_price).How to solve this error.Here am attaching the screenshot and controller code for the same.

[image: Retrieved value from db]
[image: Value in db]
Controller Code

```
    function bill_view($billid)
    {
        if(!$billid) {
        redirect('report/bill_report');
        }   
        $salecode   =str_replace("_","/",$billid);
        $filter ="gm_sale.saleCode ='$salecode'";   
        $billArray  =$this->sale_model->getBillinfo($filter);

        $exshowroom='';
        $bank   ='';
        $scheme='';
        $wcoNo  ='';
        $saleId =0;
        foreach($billArray as $key=>$val) {
        $exshowroom = $val['actual_price'];
        $date   =$val['saledate'];
        $sale_to=$val['saleCustomer'];
        $saleUserId=$val['saleUserId'];
        $wcoNo  = $val['wcoNo'];
        $saleId= $val['saleId'];
        if(!is_null($val['bank']) && !empty($val['bank'])){
        $bank    =$val['bank'];
        }
        if(!is_null($val['scheme_id']) && !empty($val['scheme_id'])){

          $array_scheme = unserialize($val['scheme_id']);
                ///////////////////////////////////////////
                foreach ($array_scheme as $val_scheme_id) {
                        $res_scheme = $this->db->get_where("gm_scheme",array('id'=>(int)$val_scheme_id));
                        if($res_scheme->num_rows >0){
                            $arrscheme      = $res_scheme->row_array();
                            if(!empty($scheme)) {
                            $scheme .= ",";
                            }
                        $scheme     .= $arrscheme['schemeName'];
                        }
                }
                /////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
        break;
        }

        $query  = $this->db->get_where('gm_users',array('userId'=>(int)$saleUserId));
            if($query->num_rows >0) {
            $arrUser    =$query->row_array();
            }else{
                $arrUser    =array();
            }

        $data['list_product']   =   $billArray;

        $data['exshowroom']=$exshowroom;
        $data['userinfo']   =$arrUser;  
        $data['saleCode']   =$salecode;
        $data['sale_to']    =$sale_to;
        $data['added_date'] =$date;
        $data['bank']   =$bank;
        $data['scheme'] =$scheme;
        $data['wcoNo']  =$wcoNo;
        $data['saleId'] =$saleId;
        $this->load->view('header_login');
        $this->load->view('report/bill_view',$data);
        //print_r($billArray);
        $this->load->view('footer_login');
    }
```

Model Code

```
function getBillinfo($filter=''){
           $this->db->select('*,gm_sale.added_date as saledate');
            $this->db->from('gm_sale',FALSE);
            $this->db->join('gm_products',"gm_sale.productId=gm_products.productId",FALSE);
            $this->db->join('gm_model',"gm_products.model_id=gm_model.id",FALSE);
            $this->db->join('gm_banks',"gm_sale.bank_id=gm_banks.bank_id","LEFT");
            if($filter<>"")
            $this->db->where($filter,'',FALSE);
            $this->db->order_by('gm_sale.saleId',"desc");
            $query = $this->db->get();
            print_r($query);
                if($query->num_rows>0) {
                $arrRow =$query->result_array();
                print_r($arrRow);
                return($arrRow);
            }
            return(array());
        }
```

Comment: what is `FALSE` in join statement?

Comment: @kumar_v..If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code that you have in the controller doing DB stuff should be in the model.

The controller does not have context to

```
$this->db
```

modify your joins (3rd param) to retrieve values in actual_price

Comment: $billArray=$this->sale_model->getBillinfo($filter);No Change the same issue

Comment: is sale_model an actual mode and getBillinfo the above method in your post? have you loaded the sale_model in your controller? any errors?

Comment: The Model sale_model is already there.I have pasted the model  code in the controller To check whether the db is getting data or not.Its already loaded by default .This was a running project.For maintenance purpose, i recently added one extra filed that is "actual_price",that field is not retrieving.Other field are working fine

Comment: what is the query that gets executed? try printing this using $this->db->last_query() after the query executes ($this->db->get())

Comment: u meant to do like this  ($this->db->get()) ;$this->db->last_query() ;print_r($this);

Comment: $query = $this->db->get(); echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45882/discussion-between-nidheesh-and-raj)